# UI Initialization Slow in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a large Silverlight application that is divided into "tabs", each of them divided further into subtabs. The xap file don't take too long to download, and the first screen is a login. After logging in, however, the app's RootVisual is set to my "mainPage", which contains all my main tabs. Since each of these contains subtabs, and each subtab contains my graphical user controls, essentially every ui component of my app is loaded when the main page loads. Thus, the login "freezes" for about 30 seconds while my main page loads all the usercontrols for my app. What is the best way to split this up so the entire app's ui isn't loaded at initialization? I was thinking not call each controls InitializeComponent() until it's parent tab is actually clicked on? Or not loading a main tab's "subtabs" until it is clicked on? Surely there must be a better way to split this up.

Comment: Have you adopted any form of MVVM with maybe some additional support from something like Caliburn Micro?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the tabcontrol Silverlight itself takes care of these things. It doesn't render the control until TabItem is selected. Make sure you haven't written anycode inside the constructor of any control. All codes should go on Loaded event of any cotrol whether it is usercontrol/custom control Hence you will be able to imporve the performance of your application.

Let me know if you still have the same issue.

Cheers!
Vinod